# Jquery Find Active Class And Replace that class

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, onclick, toggleclass

[image]

From the above image currently 1st View Details is clicked so it is showing as Hide Details.

if i click on 3 rd View Details all 1st one or(Active one) has to be relaced to view details how can i do that..?

Here what i have tried:

**Hide Details:**

```
$("#tbodyid" ).on( "click", ".hide-details", function() {
$("#participantsForGd").hide();
var field = $(this);
field.text("View Details");
field.addClass("view-details");
field.removeClass("hide-details");
});
```

**View-datails**

```
$("#tbodyid" ).on( "click", ".view-details", function() {
$("#participantsForGd").show();
var field = $(this);
field.text("Hide Details");
field.addClass("hide-details");
field.removeClass("view-details");
});
```

My html:

```
<?php while($grpData = $grpQuery->fetch_assoc()){ ?>
<tr>
<td>
<span id="<?php echo $grpData['group_id'];?>" class="view-details">View Details</span>
</td>
</tr>
<?php } ?>
```

This one has to work like toggle:

```
<form id="participantsForGd" >BLAH BLAH </form>
```

Comment: Add your html to better understanding

Comment: what you are doing seems legit. If it's not working then there is something wrong with the overall logic or the html. Show your html too. And are these buttons added dynamically?

Comment: @Mohammad Updated the question please check

Comment: @TolgaEvcimen  Yes.! button are adding dynamically

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your html structure is not good to do this task easily. I am showing how you perform this task. Then you can modify as your need.

HTML:

```
<button class='details-btn hide-details'>Hide Details</button>
<button class='details-btn view-details'>View Details</button>
<button class='details-btn view-details'>View Details</button>
<button class='details-btn view-details'>View Details</button>
```

JQuery:

```
$('.details-btn').click(function(){
    $('.details-btn').each(function(){
        $(this).removeClass('hide-details').addClass('view-details').text('View Details');
    });
    $(this).removeClass('view-details').addClass('hide-details').text('Hide Details');
})
```

Answer (score 1):

I think your php code will generate dom structure as below:

```
<table>
    <tbody id="tbodyid">
    <tr>
        <td id="group-id-1" class="details view-details">View Details</td>
        <td id="group-id-2" class="details view-details">View Details</td>
        <td id="group-id-3" class="details view-details">View Details</td>
        <td id="group-id-4" class="details view-details">View Details</td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

And you have four divs which contains details for each button.

```
<div id="participantsForGd-1" class="participantsForGd"></div>
<div id="participantsForGd-2" class="participantsForGd"></div>
<div id="participantsForGd-3" class="participantsForGd"></div>
<div id="participantsForGd-4" class="participantsForGd"></div>
```

My solution is :

```
$('#tbodyid').on('click', '.details', function(){
    $('.details').each(function(){
        $(this).removeClass('hide-details').addClass('view-details').text('View Details');
    });
    $('.participantsForGd').each(function(){
        $(this).hide();
    });
    $(this).removeClass('view-details').addClass('hide-details').text('Hide Details');
    $('#participantsForGd-' + $(this).attr('id').split('-')[2]).show();
})
```

Comment: In you code `<div id="participantsForGd-1" class="participantsForGd"></div>`  it is not dynamic and it is unique i want show details in that remove past and show current. @vanzand

Comment: Oh, got it! It is unique, and change details will be eaiser. @AbidAli